# Convert string to multiline/raw string in LUA

Tags: lua

Is there a way to convert a quoted string to a multiline string?

Something like "This string \66 here" to [[This string \66 here]] since I would like to ignore the interpretation of escaped characters.

Comment: They are all strings. There is no need to convert between them. The only difference is the syntax used to write them down inside a Lua file.

Comment: @Kroltan I'd like to be able to handle line breaks and escaped quotes after conversion

Comment: What do you need to "handle"? Do you need to extract specific lines, or what? There's no need to worry about the _contents_ of a string, unless you actually want to process it. And then, it really depends on what you want to do with it. (and if you don't understand, ask how to do _that_)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Lua 5.3 Reference Manual 3.1: Lexical Conventions](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.1)

> Literal strings can also be defined using a long format enclosed by
>   long brackets. We define an opening long bracket of level n as an
>   opening square bracket followed by n equal signs followed by another
>   opening square bracket. So, an opening long bracket of level 0 is
>   written as [[, an opening long bracket of level 1 is written as [=[,
>   and so on. A closing long bracket is defined similarly; for instance,
>   a closing long bracket of level 4 is written as ]====]. A long literal
>   starts with an opening long bracket of any level and ends at the first
>   closing long bracket of the same level. It can contain any text except
>   a closing bracket of the same level. Literals in this bracketed form
>   can run for several lines, do not interpret any escape sequences, and
>   ignore long brackets of any other level. Any kind of end-of-line
>   sequence (carriage return, newline, carriage return followed by
>   newline, or newline followed by carriage return) is converted to a
>   simple newline.
>
> For convenience, when the opening long bracket is immediately followed
>   by a newline, the newline is not included in the string.

That's all you need to know about long strings.

It does not make much sense to convert a string that has been defined using quotes "some string" to a string like [[some string]] as both quotes and square brackets are not actually part of that string and the string itself is the same.
The only difference would be a leading newline which is ignored in square brackets or escape sequences which are not interpreted.

Quotes and square brackets are only part of the string if you have nested strings. In this case conversion also doesn't make much sense because you cannot nest strings with quotes like strings with brackets.

Maybe your whole approach is a bit off?

Answer (score -1):

Do you look for something like this?

```
local db = "google"
local tbl = "accounts"
local where = "field = 'VALUE' AND TRUE"
local order = "id DESC"

local query = string.format([[
    SELECT *
    FROM `%s`.`%s`
    WHERE %s
    ORDER BY %s
]], db, tbl, where, order)
```